# Does Thai muskmelon (AKA Thai best or Tang Thai) do well in a dry climate?

Tags: vegetables, optimal-conditions, humidity, cucurbits, melons

I read about a kind of melon called Thai best. I think it's popular in Thailand. Anyway, that's where it comes from. According to websites online, fruits mature extremely quickly (60 to 65 days after sowing).

My main concern about these, though, is that they might not do well in a dry climate (it is said to be great in hot, humid climates). I live in a dry climate (not Arizona dry, but dry).

Would these melons grow in a dry climate? Does anyone know the scientific name? I'm guessing it would be something like *Cucumis melo* 'Thai Long Muskmelon', but that might be another variety. They look like little long watermelons on the outside, with a light-colored flesh and seeds grouped somewhat like a cantaloupe in the inside.

I see it listed on several websites: [evergreenseeds.com](http://www.evergreenseeds.com/thmethbe.html), [seedman.com](http://www.seedman.com/melons.htm), [lionseeds.com](http://www.lionseeds.com/seeds/thai-melon/thai-melon/), [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/50-Seeds-Long-Thai-musk-melon-muskmelon-Free-shipping-/320399933993).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do like humidity, but low humidity isn't fatal, and you can get quite a decent crop without it. What is important is:

- high soil temperature
- high soil moisture
- high soil fertility
- high soil organic matter content
- high light levels
- loose soil texture

Adding compost is good, the more the better, even if you end up with almost straight compost. Keep in mind, this fast maturing feature only 'works' when the soil and air temperatures are staying high, so planting super early doesn't necessarily mean an early crop, because the first growth will be extremely slow.

And the scientific name is *Cucumis melo* 'Thai Long Muskmelon', like you thought. At least, that seems to be the most common one.